# Creating Perspective without Webkit Perspective

Tags: css, transform

I've tried googling this but can't find it anywhere.

Is there a way to scale a div from say 375px of height on the left, to 275px of height on the right?

like this:

[a trapezoid shape http://www.disennocreative.com/img/perspect_box_bg.png](http://www.disennocreative.com/img/perspect_box_bg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `<div>` isn't going to contain anything, if it's just for looks, then you can just style its border to look like that:

```
#yourDiv {
    height:375px; /* height of the left side */
    width:0;
    border-right:none;
    border-left:50px solid gray; /* width of the "div" */

    border-top:50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:50px solid transparent; /* 375 - 50 - 50 = 275 */
}
```

But if you want to be able to put stuff inside the `<div>`, you could do something similar, using an extra, empty element before and after the content:

```
<div class="skewedBefore"></div>
<div>blah blah blah</div>
<div class="skewedAfter"></div>

.skewedBefore, .skewedAfter {
    height:0; width:0;
    border-left:100px solid gray; /* width of the content div */
}
.skewedBefore { border-top:50px solid transparent }
.skewedAfter { border-bottom:50px solid transparent }
```

You could even use pseudo-elements (:before, :after) for that second solution if you wanted to.

Comment: Very clever. Thanks for the suggestion. I had to adjust the height to 275, but it's working!

Comment: Currently, I have an image in there. I wish there was a way to make this more dynamic, so that there'd be a smooth box made from a height of x to a height of y across a length of z.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [CSS3 transforms](http://www.zenelements.com/blog/css3-transform/).  you can skew and scale to your heart's content.

Comment: So far I haven't found a transform that fits this description. Would be nice to find one though!

Comment: @William: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) on how to use `matrix3d` to map any four points to any other four points, e.g. a rectangular image to a quadrilateral of arbitrary shape.